# Error using dotnet in Jenkins for NetCore 1.1 projects

Tags: jenkins, .net-core

I have two basic NetCore project (just a Console app).
- One with NetCore 2.0 target and the other with NetCore 1.1.
- I'm using "dotnet build xxxx.csproj" to build de project

**The question is**, Do you know why NetCore 2.0 build correctly and why NetCore 1.1 cannot build in the same way?

**Detail error:**
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\NuGet.targets(102,5): error : U2nable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json."

**Additional information**:
**- dotnet --info** 
Version:            2.0.2
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a04b4bf512

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.1.7601
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win7-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d

**dotnet nuget --version**
NuGet Command Line
4.4.0.3

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

Regards
Juanlu

Comment: "Unable to load the service index for source" sounds like nuget.org is having connectivity issues. Is this issue consistently reproducible? Can the jenkins box ping api.nuget.org succesfully?

Comment: Yes,  just only for NET core 1.1 (.csproj) project, but no for NET core 2.0 (.csproj). According to PING. it's not work for NetCore 1.1 but It's works perfectly for NetCore 2.0. After that I supouse NetCore 2.0 include all packages inside (Microsoft.AspNetCore.All), and not for NetCore 1.1 inside (Microsoft.NETCore.App)!  Thanks !

Comment: Could you share your csproj files? I have a feeling that you might be including some NuGet packages which aren't compatible with .NET Core 1.x. If you can't share them, create a new console app like this `dotnet new console --framework netcoreapp1.0` and attempt to restore package for it.

Comment: Try add a global.json do your .net 1.1 project to set the sdk version to 1.1.x and make sure to install that sdk version. Just having the .NET Core SDK 2.0.2 will not build a .NET Core app version 1.1

Comment: Solved! Finally two problems inside Jenkins box: (1) NuGet.Config was modified in a wrong way, so I had to repaired it . (2) NetCore 2.0.2 don't need to download anything  because it uses "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Al", so restore package is OK everytime. For Netcore 1.1 It doesn't works, because need download packages, but after repair NuGet.config, everything works perfectly right now!  Thank you very much!